# AJAX - How to update cart count and check for status changes every 5 minutes

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have 2 similar questions (both related to Ajax, not too familiar with it)

The first is, I have an AJAX updating my cart in Woocommerce. I have 2 "mini-carts" - one for desktop and a different one for mobile. The one for desktop is functioning perfectly. The cart count doesn't show until there is a product in it, and once AJAX adds a product the count shows.

The mobile one is a bit different. It is updating fine and the count shows, but the page needs to be refreshed in order to see the count. I know the issue is due to the IF statement, but I can't figure out how to show the count if something is added via AJAX, without a page refresh (I hope that makes sense).

**Below is the code in my footer.php file**

```
<a class="col" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mobileAccountModal">
            <img src="/img/cart-icon-mobile.svg" />
            CART
        </a>
        <?php
            if ( is_woocommerce_activated() ) { 
                    $count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count; ?>
                        <?php if ( $count > 0 ) { ?>
                            <span class="cart-contents-count" id="test-cart"><?php
                        $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
                        echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
                        ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>                                                   
        <?php } ?>
```

**And below the functions.php file.**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count', 50, 1 );
function refresh_cart_count( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="cart-contents-count" id="test-cart"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
    ?></span>
    <?php
     $fragments['#test-cart'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

The second question is very similar. I have a section that displays ORDER STATUS on the front-end and displays different HTML (div with the message) depending on the status. This is working fine, however, the page needs to be refreshed in order to see the updates.

Is there a way I can check for status updates via AJAX every 5 minutes? TIA

Comment: Note that in StackOverFlow the rule is one question at the time…

Comment: Oh! Wasn't aware, apologies.